# Get mask from tensor of indices?

Tags: tensorflow

If I have a tensor of shape "batch_size * length * hidden_size", and I have another index span tensor of shape "batch_size * 2", where the index span tensor indicates the beginning and ending indices I want to select from the first tensor. Say if the index span tensor has values

```
[[1,3], [2, 4]]
```

then I want to get the following mask from the first tensor

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...]]
```

Is there a way to do it with Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

We can obtain the above my using a combination of `range` (to obtain the indices) and  `tf.sparse_to_dense` (to populate the ones):

```
batch_size = 2
length_hidden_size = 10

# Use range to populate the indices
r = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.range(x[0], x[1]+1),a)

# convert to full indices
mesh = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(tf.shape(r)[1]), tf.range(tf.shape(r)[0]))[1]
full_indices = tf.reshape(tf.stack([mesh, r], axis=2), [-1,2])

# Set 1s to the full indices
val = tf.ones(tf.shape(full_indices)[0])
dense = tf.sparse_to_dense(full_indices,tf.constant([batch_size,length_hidden_size]), val, validate_indices=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(dense))
#[[0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: If the lengths of the mask spans (number of 1's in each row) are different, is there a way to do it?